# Avy is not labelling every character I want to jump to

Tags: avy

I can't jump to every instance of a character, for instance consider this line :

`if( c == '\n' ||  c == ' ' || c == '\n') continue;`

Pressing `avy-shortcut SPACE` to label all the white spaces will only allow me to jump at the spaces between the `c` and the `=`, all the other spaces after and before the `(, ), |` are ignored. Any idea on how to fix this behavior ?

Comment: what command are you acutally using ? avy-goto-char ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like your avy shortcut is bound to `avy-goto-word-1`, while what you want here is `avy-goto-char`.

Try `M-x avy-goto-char SPC` and you will see that when word boundaries are ignored, all spaces are matched. On the other hand, `avy-goto-word-1` is searching for a word boundary followed by a space. In your example text that happens to find the spaces following the word "c".

You'll see the same behavior with `M-x search-forward-regexp RET \b SPC` (ie search forward for the regular expression `\b` followed by a space). In Emacs regular expressions, `\b` matches the empty string at the beginning or end of word, where the current syntax table defines what characters are considered part of a word.